# MPdf is not displaying pdf, instead showing error loading PDF in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf, mpdf

I'm trying to display an html table in PDF format using MPDF - PDF Library but it shows 'error loading PDF' message.

Things I tried:-

1. Made sure there is no extra space before the opening tag and after the PHP ending tag.
2. Removed all the Javascript and CSS Codes in that specific page.
3. Created another page that consisted only MDPF code for creating pdf from html and displaying.
4. Finally tried another PDF Library i.e. dompdf
5. Installed the PDF Viewer Plugin in Google Chrome Browser
6. Disabled the PHP display_errors in wp-config.php file of wordpress
7. Made use of ob_start and ob_clean. But not sure if I used it in a correct way

None of the above worked for me and the results were the same

The code is below:-

```
  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$sql = "select  a.case_id as id, a.remarks ,a.caseNumber,c.fname,a.date,
a.NextDate,a.CaseType, a.courtName from  wp_cases a , wp_clients
 as c where   a.client_id=c.client_id and a.status=1";

    if ($results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql))
   { 
   //$echomsg="%PDF-";
    $echomsg= "<table  style=\"font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;\" class=\"table\">";
 $echomsg.= "<thead style=\"background-color:lightblue;\">
    <tr>
    <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">No</th>
     <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">Details</th>
     <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\"> Date</th>
     <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">  Client Name</th>
     <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\"> Case Number</th>
      <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">  CourtName</th>
       <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">  Case Type</th>
        <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: center;padding: 8px;\">Next Date</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>";
  //<th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> delete</th>
  $c=1;
       foreach ($results as $result)
       { 
         $echomsg.= " <tr>
       <th style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->id</a></th>
        <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->remarks</a></td>
        <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->date</a></td>
       <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->fname</a></td>
       <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->caseNumber</a></td>
       <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->courtName</a></td>
       <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->CaseType</a></td>
        <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"cases?currcase_id=$result->id\">$result->NextDate</a></td>


       </tr>";
       // <td style=\" border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left;padding: 8px;\"> <a href=\"payment?delpay_id=$result->id\"><button class=\"btn\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></button></a></td>

        $c+=1;
       }
        $echomsg.= "</tbody>
      </table>";

     //ob_start();

//echo  $echomsg;

  $mpdf->SetTitle('Case');
$mpdf->SetAuthor('Afaf');
$mpdf->SetCreator('Afaf');
$mpdf->SetSubject('Case');
// WRITE HTML
$mpdf->WriteHTML($echomsg);
// OUTPUT, SHOW IN BROWSER BY DEFAULT
$mpdf->Output(); 


/*$dompdf = new Dompdf();
     $dompdf->loadHtml($echomsg);
      $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
      $dompdf->render();
      $dompdf->stream("Cases",array("Attachment"=>0)); */

/*ob_clean();
flush();
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='case.pdf'"); 
exit; */
   }
```

The things I tried are there in the commented form in the code.

**Edit**
Opened the downloaded PDF with notepad. The following code was there:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="en-US" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>Cases &#8211; LawyerMgmt</title>
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="LawyerMgmt &raquo; Feed" href="https://oursite.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="LawyerMgmt &raquo; Comments Feed" href="https://oursite.com/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/12.0.0-1\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/12.0.0-1\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"wpemoji":"https:\/\/oursite.com\/wp-includes\/
```

PS: The PDF displays only in Microsoft Edge Browser but it shows 'Corrupted file' when downloaded from there

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: did you have something like: $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(); in your code, I cannot see it? how does this work?!

Comment: Yes it is there in the beginning of the page. Since the code is very long i chose only above part to be posted. Following is the code present in the beginning of the page  
     `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`

Comment: I see, I have tried your code on my local machine and it works! (with some fake data). Can you try the `$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD);` and check if still downloads a corrupted file?

Comment: Yes it says the file is corrupted even after adding your code. Did you try this on a wordpress website? Because mine is being tried on a wordpress website and showing error

Comment: **Update**: I tried on google chrome it works perfectly fine since it has an PDF Viewer extension installed , however when I try to open the downloaded file in Adobe it says its corrupted

Comment: No, I just tried it on a plain PHP file from scratch. And I think the browser has nothing to do with the corrupted file! Because the file is being generated from the server. Maybe you have some warnings being printed so they mess the pdf structure. Can you just echo the HTML you are generating without Outputting a pdf, just print $echomsg;

Comment: It displays the table perfectly without any errors